# Easiest way to scale php and mysql website

Tags: scalability, cloud-hosting, scale

I have read many info about optimizing websites (varnish, caching...)
All these look quite complex.

I wonder if cloud hosting can help me. Are there automatic scaling solutions ?
Simplicity is the keyword for me.

Comment: "Cloud" is an abstraction which defines a machine or set of machines connected via network, not a technology. Opting "cloud" carries no specific definition or technology. Also, the amount of scale you're talking about changes the strategies and approach significantly. Scaling, is quite simply, not simple.

Answer (score 1):

scaling is not simple. It's why certain people that are very good at building a system that scales and others that are good at designing the code to scale get paid a lot of money for their work. Cloud is not the end all solution to scale.